# Уникальное поле в MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

Использую Spring Data MongoDB.
Вот описание коллекции:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = { "id" })
@Document(collection = "book")
public class BookEntity {
  @Id
  private String id;

  @Field("book_name")
  @Indexed(unique = true) //Это означает что полне уникальное
  private String bookName;
}
```

При добавлении и при изменении записи я все равно могу добавлять одинаковые поля bookName, ни какой ошибки не получаю.
Добавление записей делаю через репозиторий

```
bookRepository.save(obj);
bookRepository.update(obj);
```

вот сам репозиторий:

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends MongoRepository<BookEntity, String> {

}
```

Что я упустил?

Comment: @Column(unique = true) ?

Comment: На сколько я понял Column с MongoDB не работает. Он только для SQL БД

Comment: Взгляните на этот ответ https://stackoverflow.com/a/66447448/8696557
Возможно нужно дополнительно в конфигурации прописать чтобы индексы создавались автоматически.

Answer (score 0):

Введи в application.yml:

```
 auto-index-creation: true
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]